# JMS Timeout or TimeToLive

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, java-ee-6

I am fairly new to Java EE and JMS and am looking at doing an implementation using JMS.

Think of the following scenario:

**Scenario**

A user hits a servlet. A message is then put into a JMS server/Queue from this servlet. A response is then sent back to the user saying "Message Queued".

**Option 1**

The consumer/MDB receives the message from the JMS queue and processes it. This is normal operation and pretty standard.

**Option 2**

There is no consumer(for what ever reason) or the receiver is processing messages too slow. So what I would like is for the message in the queue to timeout. Once timed out, and email should be sent etc (email is just as an example).

Reading the API spec/Java EE 6 tutorial I have found in the QueuSender class

```
void send(Message message, int deliveryMode, int priority, long timeToLive)
```

So by settings the timeToLive the message will be evicted from the queue. The problem is that the is no "interface/call back" to know that the message was evicted. It just disappears. Or am I mistaken?

Another approach I thought of was for a thread to monitor the queue and evict messages that are "expired" and pull them from the queue. But I don't think that is possible, is it?

Any light shed on this matter would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of some implementation specific functionality to fulfill your requirements. The JMS specification does neither define which action is taken with a timed out message, nor does it offer you any reasonable criteria selection when polling messages from a queue.

Most (if not all) JMS implementations do however offer the concept of DLQs (dead letter queues). If a message cannot be delivered to a regular consumer or times out, the JMS implementation will most likely be able to move the message to a DLQ, which is basically also a regular queue with its own listener.

So, if you set up two queues, Q1 and Q2 and configure Q2 as a DLQ for Q1, you would do your normal request processing in a listener on Q1 and implement an additional listener for Q2 to do the error/timeout handling.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. I will give this a try but its obviously implementation specific. I believe this is an area the EE API spec overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous interaction over JMS might be of help to you either. Basicly on the client side you:

1. send a message with a correlation id and time-to-live
2. receive a message (usually in the same thread) using the same correlation id and specifying timeout (time-to-live == timeout so if you treat it dead, it's really dead)

On the other side, server:

1. on an incoming message must fetch the correlation id
2. specify that correlation id for a response while sending it back to the client.
   Of course server must be quick enough to fit the timeout/time-to-live threshold.

So on the client side you are always sure what's happend to the message that was sent.